# UITableViewCellStyle Subtitle auto layout changes from iOS 10 to iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios10, ios11

Using iOS 11, I can successfully get a self-sizing `UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle` cell to dynamically adjust its height by setting the `numberOfLines` property on the `detailTextLabel` to 0.

```
public class SubtitleCell: UITableViewCell {
    public override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        self.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    }
}
```

I've also ensured auto-resizing is enabled on the tableView.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In iOS 11, with only these two changes, I get a resized cell. Great!

[image]

However, in iOS 10, with the same code, my table view cells do not resize.

[image]

I know that iOS 11 made autoresizing table views the default. However, I did not believe that Apple made any other functional changes to table views or table view cells.

Why, even when enabling autoresizing table views, I cann't get the `subtitle` cell style to resize properly? When I use the live view inspector, I don't see any constraints in the table view cell on either the iOS 11 or iOS 10 cells. So, I feel like Apple made an underlying change to the default UITableViewCell styles, but I cannot find any reference to it.

[Sample Project](https://github.com/chrismanderson/Heightbug)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10, in order to enable self sizing functionality you had to subclass a `UITableViewCell`, and add constraints for the `Custom` style cell. Note, it doesn't work for `Subtitle` style cells as Apple doesn't give you the ability to add constraints to the subtitle label and title to the frame of the table view cell.

You'd also have to supply a raw value instead for `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` in iOS 10.

You could use availability checks to run different cell configurations for the `SubtitleCell` for iOS 10 and 11.

Comment: What I'm still confused on is that I don't see any constraints for the `Subtitle` cell style even in iOS 11. Do we think Apple is doing the layout 'manually' for these cell styles in iOS 11?

Comment: I believe there are constraints on the subtitle cell labels in iOS 11 but **not** iOS 10. On both versions of iOS Xcode hides these constraints under the hood.

Comment: Hides the constraints?! That seems so sketch. Going to radar this one.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10, for the cell of style Subtitle i.e default cell (not custom), this code is not adjusting the cell's dimension as per text label contents.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

So you have to use a custom cell and add a label with all constraints (top, bottom, leading, trailing) and the number of lines should be 0.

Otherwise, you have to add a check for iOS 11 and above, and else for lower versions add height as per need.

```
 if #available(iOS 11, *) {
     // iOS 11 (or newer) Swift code
            return UITableView.automaticDimension;
  } 
  else {
     // iOS 10 or older code
            return 70
  }
```